# order taxonomy alphabetical

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms

I am trying everything to get my custom taxonomy to display alphabetical but nothing seems to work. I have added orderby=title and name but the tax list still displays the order of how it was posted. This is what I have going on. The snippet is used to display current post information based on the selected tax. I have two sets of tax assigned to a post (year and category) on the front end once I click the year and the post I want to view it displays all the information along with the category  list. The category list is controlled as well as a tax but for some reason I am unable to get this list to display alphabetical but instead it is posted based on publish date. Below is my code

```
 function get_related_posts( $taxonomy = '', $args = array() ) {
if ( !is_single() )
    return false;
/* Check if we have a valid taxonomy*/
if ( !$taxonomy ) 
    return false;
$taxonomy = filter_var( $taxonomy, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
if ( !taxonomy_exists( $taxonomy ) )
    return false;
$current_post = get_queried_object();

/* Get the post terms, just the ids*/
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $current_post->ID, $taxonomy, array( 'fields' => 'ids') );
/* Lets only continue if we actually have post terms and if we don't have an WP_Error object. If not, return false*/
if ( !$terms || is_wp_error( $terms ) )
    return false;
/* Set the default query arguments*/
$defaults = array(
    'post_type' => $current_post->post_type,
    'post__not_in' => array( $current_post->ID),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
            'terms' => $terms,
            'include_children' => false,
            'orderby' => 'title',
        ),
    ),
);
/* Validate and merge the defaults with the user passed arguments*/
if ( is_array( $args ) ) {
    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
} else {
    $args = $defaults;
}

$q = get_posts( $args );

return $q;
 }
if ( function_exists( 'get_related_posts' ) ) {
    $related_posts = get_related_posts( 'juryyear', array( 'posts_per_page' => 99,) );
    if ( $related_posts ) {
        foreach ( $related_posts as $post ) {
            setup_postdata( $post );
?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?>"><?php $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'jury_category' ); foreach ( $terms as $term ) { echo $term->name; }?></a></li>
<? } wp_reset_postdata(); } }?>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I needed to add 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC', to $related_posts = get_related_posts( 'juryyear', array( 'posts_per_page' => 99,) );